# Error while installing imagick

Tags: php, cpanel, whm

I'm trying to install imagemagick and imagick module in whm. I installed imagemagick without any problem, but when installing imagick through whm, I am getting the following error :

```
downloading imagick-3.0.1.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.0.1.tgz (Unknown size)
....done: 3,582 bytes
Could not get contents of package "/root/tmp/pear/cache/imagick-3.0.1.tgz". Invalid tgz file.
Download of "pecl/imagick" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/imagick"
Download failed
install failed
The imagick.so object is not in /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: just to be sure... your working on linux, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the http://pecl.php.net was down! So what I did was to download the package from google code site and installed it manually.

```
cd /usr/src/
wget http://acelnmp.googlecode.com/files/imagick-3.0.1.tgz
tar -xvf imagick-3.0.1.tgz
cd imagick-3.0.1
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

then added the extension on php.ini and restarted the server:

```
echo "extension=imagick.so" >> /usr/local/lib/php.ini 
service httpd restart
```

Comment: with whm, may need to first install ImageMagick with `/scripts/installimagemagick`

Comment: Huge help! Pecl seemed to still be up but for some reason I was getting the same error. I just ran your code and it worked perfectly. You rock!!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that make was not installed for me. Try:

yum groupinstall "Development Tools"